# My qsort array of strings in alphabetical order won't work

Tags: c

I'm currently having problems with my qsort. I'm trying to sort an array of strings I read from a file in the qsort function. I want it to be read alphabetically, but it isnt working. I would've liked to attached my file as well, but it is very long. This is my code:

```
int sammenlign_hold(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    rytterdata2017 *resultat1 = (rytterdata2017 *)p1;
    rytterdata2017 *resultat2 = (rytterdata2017 *)p2;

    if (strcmp(resultat1 -> rytterhold, resultat2 -> rytterhold) == 0)
        return strcmp(resultat1 -> rytterFornavn, resultat2 -> rytterFornavn);
    else
        return strcmp(resultat1 -> rytterhold, resultat2 -> rytterhold);
} 

void opgave_2(rytterdata2017 *alle_rytterdata2017) {
    rytterdata2017 arr[100];

    int k = 0;
    int i = 0; 

    for (i = 0; i < PERSONER; i++) {
        if(strcmp(alle_rytterdata2017[i].nationalitet, "DEN") == 0) {
           strcpy(arr[k].rytterFornavn,    alle_rytterdata2017[i].rytterFornavn);
           strcpy(arr[k].rytterhold, alle_rytterdata2017[i].rytterhold);
           k++;
       }       
   }

    qsort(arr, k, sizeof(alle_rytterdata2017), sammenlign_hold); 

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        printf("%s %s \n", arr[i].rytterhold, arr[i].rytterFornavn);
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(alle_rytterdata2017)` will give you the size of a pointer, not the size of the array

Comment: indeed. You need to pass in the size of the array. Also, [mcve].

Comment: As a developer it's crucial to learn how to debug your programs: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @pm100 I think maybe it should be `sizeof(*alle_rytterdata2017)` to get the size of the array type?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I tried to change it to sizeof(*alle_rytterdata2017) but it still didnt work for some reason.

Comment: @ullahula the `sizeof` operator returns the number of bytes needed to hold the value of a variable. `alle_rytterdata2017` is a pointer, `sizeof(alle_rytterdata2017)` gives you the numbers of bytes needed to store a pointer, `sizeof(*alle_rytterdata2017)` gives you the numbers of bytes needed to store a `rytterdata2017` object. `opgave_2` must get from the caller the number of elements as well.

Comment: @ullahula Interesting.  I tried it on my machine with some test code of my own and it worked; I would think it would be equivalent in effect to Kamul's solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the parameter size passed to qsort function.
`sizeof(alle_rytterdata2017)` will give you size of a pointer to rytterdata2017.
`qsort` however sorts data that are of `rytterdata2017` size. You should pass `sizeof(arr[0])` or `sizeof(rytterdata017)` to `qsort`.

Please include more source code, with struct definitions for future questions.
I have written the following code for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
  char rytterhold[20];
  char nationalitet[20];
  char rytterFornavn[20];
} rytterdata2017;

int sammenlign_hold(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
rytterdata2017 *resultat1 = (rytterdata2017 *)p1;
rytterdata2017 *resultat2 = (rytterdata2017 *)p2;
int temp;
if ((temp = strcmp(resultat1 -> rytterhold, resultat2 -> rytterhold)) == 0) 
return strcmp(resultat1 -> rytterFornavn, resultat2 -> rytterFornavn);
    else
    return temp; 
 // strcmp(resultat1 -> rytterhold, resultat2 -> rytterhold);
 // tip: don't call strcmp twice, it is cpu extensive
}

void opgave_2(rytterdata2017 *alle_rytterdata2017, size_t PERSONER) {
rytterdata2017 arr[100];
int k = 0;
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < PERSONER; i++) {
 if(strcmp(alle_rytterdata2017[i].nationalitet, "DEN") == 0) {
           strcpy(arr[k].rytterFornavn,    alle_rytterdata2017[i].rytterFornavn);
           strcpy(arr[k].rytterhold, alle_rytterdata2017[i].rytterhold);
           k++;
       }
   }

 // qsort(arr, k, sizeof(alle_rytterdata2017), sammenlign_hold); // no error, but sizeof(alle_rytterdata2017) is ont size of the object stored in arr
 qsort(arr, k, sizeof(arr[0]), sammenlign_hold);
 // or qsort(arr, k, sizeof(*alle_rytterdata2017), sammenlign_hold);
 // or qsort(arr, k, sizeof(alle_rytterdata2017[0]), sammenlign_hold);
 // or qsort(arr, k, sizeof(rytterdata2017), sammenlign_hold);
 // on my machine:
 // sizeof(alle_rytterdata2017) = 8
 // sizeof(*alle_rytterdata2017) = sizeof(rytterdata2017) = 60

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
printf("%s %s \n", arr[i].rytterhold, arr[i].rytterFornavn);
} }
int
main ()
{
    rytterdata2017 arr[] = {
        {"c","DEN","b"},
        {"a","DEN","e"},
        {"c","DEN","a"},
        {"d","DEN","c"},
        {"d","DEN","a"},
        {"b","DEN","a"},
    };
    opgave_2(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
  return 0;
}
```

Which produces:

```
a e 
b a 
c a 
c b 
d a 
d c
```

Comment: Note: `()` are not needed in `sizeof(arr[0])`.  `sizeof arr[0]` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Program below sorts array of strings using pointer to `strcmp` function which compares strings alphabetically. Before this just read from file into `str` array.

```
int main () {
  int i;
  char str[3][10] = {"one", "two", "three"};

  qsort(str, 3, 10, (int(*) (const void*, const void*)) strcmp);

  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      printf("%s\n", str[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but are you saying that the structure of my qsort is wrong because your example seems very different from mine. Also, thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: It's difficult to read variable names in you code so I posted this shorter version that is also easier to understand. To qsort pass array, number of strings, size of each string and pointer to function which you want to use. Feel free to accept this answer.

Comment: The asker's example compares two sets of strings, so just passing in strcmp as the comparison function to qsort will likely not fit their needs.